# Nitrogen: changing targetID breaks lightbox

Tags: erlang, lightbox, nitrogen

I'm using Nitrogen & lightbox. I'm looking for some guidance after spending way too long trying to understand why a working example breaks as soon as I change the `targetID` of a lightbox.  The fragment below works if I use `"name_dialog"` or `"share_dialog"`, but not if I use `"compose_dialog"`.  I've looked through the source and style sheets, but have not found where those two are defined any differently than what I'm trying to do.

In my .hrl:

```
...
-record (compose_dialog, { ?ELEMENT_BASE(compose_dialog_element) }).
..
```

In my element module:

```
...
reflect() -> record_info(fields, compose_dialog).
render_element(_HtmlID, _Record) ->
    #lightbox { id=compose_lightbox, style="display: none;", body = [
..

show() ->
    wf:wire(compose_lightbox, #show {}).
```

Comment: I neglected to post the error message...

{error,error,badarg,
       [{io_lib,format,["~nNitrogen.$scope('~s'); ",[[compose_lightbox]]]},
        {wf_utils,f,2},
        {wf_render_actions,render_action,1},
        {wf_render_actions,render_actions,2},
        {lists,foldl,3},
        {wf_render_actions,render_actions,2},
        {wf_render_actions,call_action_render,2},
        {wf_render_actions,render_action,1}]}

Answer (score 1):

ok -- for anyone running into the same NOOB error...

What I neglected to do was add my new element on the body in webview.  As a result, I had an undefined object with no ID.  Adding it there (and making sure not to create duplicates) fixed this error.